# When I scroll of the custom listview, content doesn't seem

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am opening this topic second time because I can't find problem and nobody can't responding
I have a custom listview in tabhost in fragment. **when I scroll the custom listview, TextView contents destroy, just seem empty**. Here is my codes

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
private TabHost tabHost;
private View view;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> listMyDataIds = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView lstViewMyData;
private SQL sql;
private MyDataAdapter adpMyData;
private int i = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_content, container, false);
    initialize();
    sql = new SQL(view.getContext());
    sql.openToRead();
    listMyDataIds = sql.get(list);
    sql.close();
    adpMyData = new MyDataAdapter(view.getContext());
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    sql = new SQL(view.getContext());
    sql.openToRead();

    listMyDataIds = sql.get(list);
    String[] stockArr = new String[listMyDataIds.size()];
    stockArr = listMyDataIds.toArray(stockArr);
    lstViewMyData.setAdapter(adpMyData);

    sql.close();
}

public class MyDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context c;
    private SQL sql;
    public MyDataAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.mydata_listview_row, list);
        this.c = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mydata_listview_row, parent, false);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        TextView txt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
        sql = new SQL(c);
        sql.openToRead();
        listMyDataIds = sql.get(list);
        if (i < listMyDataIds.size()){
            txt1.setText((sql.get(list);
            txt2.setText((sql.get(list));
            txt3.setText((sql.get(list);
            i++;
        }
        sql.close();
        return v;
    }
}

private void initialize() {
    tabHost=(TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB 3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);
    // tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    lstViewMyData = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstMyData);
}
```

[image] [image] [image]

How can I fix this situation ?

Comment: You should use convert View.

Comment: And Always use Holder class that makes your Custom listview Efficient :)

Comment: Don't re-open the exact same question. If you have new information or want to make your question better, edit your previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context c;
    private SQL sql;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyDataAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.mydata_listview_row, list);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
    convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.mydata_listview_row,null);
        try {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txt1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
                holder.txt2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
                holder.txt3= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.startDate);



        sql = new SQL(c);
        sql.openToRead();
        listMyDataIds = sql.get(list);
        if (i < listMyDataIds.size()){
           holder.txt1.setText((sql.get(list);
            holder.txt2.setText((sql.get(list));
           holder.txt3.setText((sql.get(list);
            i++;
        }
        sql.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
         public TextView txt1;
        public TextView txt2;
        public TextView txt3;


    }
```

and When you Initialize Adpter write

```
adpt = new MyDataAdapter (getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.mydata_listview_row, list);
            workList.setAdapter(adpt);
```